# Identifying waterproof DIN connector

Tags: connector

Any idea who makes the following connector or what a compatible connector would be called?

[image]

I need both male and female but that company only sells female.

Comment: What did the company say when you asked them? Because you did ask them before asking here, right?

Comment: @pipe Their sales people either didn't know or didn't want to tell me.

Comment: probably propriatery ... these are similar ... http://www.switchcraft.com/productsummary.aspx?Parent=811 ... https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11475

Comment: @jsotola: The first one seems similar to one I tried where the notch is square/smaller and the pins are also smaller.  For the second one pins 1 and 2 are more separated than 4 and 5 and apparently are common in CB radios.  They're definitely hard to find, but it appears Sterilight/Viqua also uses them: http://www.servapure.com/assets/images/viqua_440155.jpg, https://viqua.com/wp-content/uploads/254NM-HF.jpg, etc.

Comment: those have a different shell ... the alicat one uses a bayonet type fastener, the servapure uses a screw type fastener

Comment: getting closer 
 ... https://connectorllt.en.alibaba.com/productlist.html?spm=a2700.8304367.breadcrumb.2.a27a567RyNHAJ

Comment: it could be a GX16-6

Comment: @jsotola: I think GX16-6 is like the CB radio one with the uneven pin separation.  See the 6-pin one here: https://www.amazon.com/GX16-6-Aviation-Connector-aviation-connector/dp/B06XFFP7PD  Also, it's definitely a screw type fastener what I'm looking for, but I think what looks like bayonet type is to remove the sleeve and access the cable leads.  The housing here looks identical: https://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/cache/image/3/5/6/b/13675.Jpg, just 2-pin instead of 6 and it's twist-lock instead of screw-lock.

Comment: you may find it here ... https://signal.en.alibaba.com/

Comment: which product is the one from allelectronics.com?

Comment: I found the image on Google but it didn't link to a product :(

Comment: https://www.allelectronics.com/item/con-225/2-pin-twist-lock-connector/1.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70780/discussion-between-nelson-rothermel-and-jsotola).

Answer (score 2):

the picture that you posted matches this `Conxall Mini-ConX® 6282-2SG-3DC`

found here ... https://www.allelectronics.com/item/con-225/2-pin-twist-lock-connector/1.html

this looks like what you are looking for

http://conxall.com/Category.aspx?Parent=815  ... EN3 product line

`Switchcraft EN3P6FX`

https://ca.mouser.com/productdetail/switchcraft/en3p6fx?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvG94qpybaIZR9xRg6HOzxYpISh3buVAnc%3D

Comment: Ok, I ordered Mini-Con 6282-6PG-513 and just tested.  It was not completely identical, but the connection part matches exactly so it will work.  The actual part would be closer to 6282-6PG-311 or 6282-6PG-315 (3-smaller plastic sleeve in the back; 11 or 15-the rubber sleeve size).  Feel free to update your answer and I'll accept since you did help me narrow it down.